# ASP.Net radio button list

Tags: asp.net

im trying to create a feedback form, i have a some mock code which looks similar to this

```
    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
    {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        Table1.Rows.Add(tr);
        TableCell QuestionCell = new TableCell();

        // get the text for the question and stick it in the cell
        QuestionCell.Text = "<b>"+i+".</b> Question " + i;
        tr.Cells.Add(QuestionCell);

        TableRow tr2 = new TableRow();
        Table1.Rows.Add(tr2);

        // create a cell for the choice

        TableCell ChoicesCell = new TableCell();
        ChoicesCell.Width = 1000;

        // align the choices on the left
        ChoicesCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
        tr2.Cells.Add(ChoicesCell);

        RadioButtonList rbl = new RadioButtonList();
        rbl.ID = "Radio1_" + i;
        ChoicesCell.Controls.Add(rbl);

        rbl.Items.Add("1");
        rbl.Items.Add("2");
        rbl.Items.Add("3");
        rbl.Items.Add("4");
    }
```

obviously this code doesn't mean anything, its just to experiment on how i can do this feedback form, the problem im having now is once some one presses the submit button (there's a submit button on the form) how do i go through the table and get text from the radio buttons the user has selected ?? the feedback from in created on page_load !!

thanks for any help !!

**EDIT** so i have this code once the button is pressed

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TableCell cell in Table1.Rows)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in cell.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is RadioButtonList)
            {
                if (ctrl.selected) // this doesnt works 
                {
                    string selected = ctrl.text // this doesnt work either 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this doesn't seem to be working ... i don't know where im going wrong !!

Comment: When you say 'this doesnt works'. What do you mean? Are you getting a specific error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would think that you would have to cast the `Control` inside your loop to be a `RadioButtonList`.

Also, try using the `SelectedValue` property instead of `selected`

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TableCell cell in Table1.Rows)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in cell.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is RadioButtonList)
            {
                string selected = ((RadioButtonList)ctrl).SelectedValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 This should definitely work for the poster.  It's important to mention that .NET languages are case sensitive, and properties of a control (such as RadioButtonList or CheckBox) are not accessible via the base type.  So, there is no such thing as `ctrl.selected` or `ctrl.Selected`, but as `((Checkbox)ctrl).Selected`, or as a RadioButtonList as you've posted.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have EnableViewState=false for those controls. The server cannot see the changed by the user state of the controls after postback if their ViewState is set to false

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating controls the way you are (pretty much on the fly) you will need to re-create these every page request in Page_Init and maintain state yourself.